# How can I make the "field_media_document_display field be filled with a 1?

Tags: migrations

Although I have the Files displayed by default set as true and when I manually add one it defaults to `1` , when I use the step one process it put s a null there . Since it has a null the next time a user tries to change the name it doesn't work.

I am using the [Migrate File Entities to Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media) module, this is my code in step 1. where can I add something to make it fill in the `field_media_document_display_field` as a `1` ?

```
field_media_document/title: title
field_media_document/target_id:
    plugin: media_file_copy
    move: FALSE
    reuse: TRUE
    path: 'public://grants/'
```

Comment: Is `field_media_document_display_field` a custom field you created? If so, what is its field type? If not, where did you find it?

Comment: its a field in this table `media__field_media_document` which i did not create .

Comment: its type is  tinyint(3)

Comment: I think I got it now, added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

In [media-migration-step1.yml.twig](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_file_to_media/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Generators/media-migration-step1.yml.twig#L52) I see:

[image]

So should be:

```
field_media_document/display: TRUE
field_media_document/target_id:
    plugin: media_file_copy
    move: FALSE
    reuse: TRUE
    path: 'public://grants/'
```

If still not, try:

```
field_media_document/display:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: TRUE
field_media_document/target_id:
    plugin: media_file_copy
    move: FALSE
    reuse: TRUE
    path: 'public://grants/'
```

Comment: i get this error - Drupal\migrate\MigrateException: Invalid process for destination 'field_media_document/display' [error]
in migration 'migd8_grants_media_step1' in

Comment: @Diana Remove the `field_media_document/title: title` and see if that fixes the issue. Maybe it thinks it's an image because of the title. As media files do not have a title.

Comment: @NoSssweat i thought it worked but it still does not work. probably because my bundle is document, not file

Comment: it still doesnt work and i get this errorDrupal\migrate\MigrateException: Invalid process for destination 'field_media_document/display' in migration

Comment: @Diana try using `true` instead of  `1`, updated the answer.